# HTML email template builder for system emails

Tags: email

I'm working on an app that is sending system emails at various points, for example welcome mails, reminders and other stuff. The app is a Spring app and is filling the emails with the parameters using a compatible templating engine like Thymeleaf. The templates for the emails themselves should be edited and created by non-technical people. Do any of you know of a setup where that works well?